# Reconfigure Tomcat database connections at runtime

Tags: java, tomcat, database-connection, jdbc-odbc

I'm working on a legacy Java web application that is deployed in a Tomcat container and accesses several databases from different vendors (Oracle, MS SQL, DB2). Currently the connections are established over the Oracle JDBC-ODBC bridge driver and datasources are configured on operating system level (Windows Server 2008).

My team recently suggested a migration to vendor specific JDBC4 drivers (which by the way are available for all used databases), but despite the widely known disadvantages in performance and functionality and the fact that Oracle explicitly states on its website that the JDBC-ODBC bridge is not suited for production and a last resort if no other driver is available, we faced some serious resistance coming from the current developers and the team responsible for operating the system.

I was told that one of the requirements is to be able to reconfigure database connections at runtime. Currently this is done by just editing the datasources configured in the Windows ODBC tool while the application is running. As far as I know this is something that's not possible with container managed (JNDI) datasources. Also it sounds rather dangerous to me since the application is in an inconsistent state during the reconfiguration process.

My question now is if the reconfiguration of datasources at runtime is a suggested practice, and if so, is there is any way we could do this using technology from this century, meaning JDBC4 over JNDI?

Comment: Glassfish allows for a dynamic reconfiguration of connection pools: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/gkoif.html

Comment: What kind of reconfiguration are we talking about? Is it for example the number of connections, or the destination of the connection itself (which would mean changing the JDBC URL and reconnecting)?

Comment: I'm talking about the destination of the connection itself.

Comment: I think that C3P9 and the new Tomcat Pool (**not** DBCP) can be configured "online" through JMX - but I'm not sure

Comment: Changing the db destination while the app is running sounds like a really bad idea. This requirement is either fictitious or erroneous. The usual procedure for changing a datasource is to change the configuration (in the context XML, for example) and then restart to pick up the change. I would challenge the developer's rational again.